# Add data in datatable row by row

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

i have following Code i want add matching data in Datatable help. how do this

```
    private void GetVehicalIdFromWeb()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(Connection1);
        conn.Open();
      //  var LIST=(from a in General.GetQueryable<Ve>)
        string Query = "Select ID,Name from Vehicle ";
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dtGetVihcale = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(dt);
        var list = General.GetQueryable<Fleet_VehicleType>(c => c.VehicleType != null);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {          

            var rowsdata = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                            where row.Field<string>("Name").Trim() == item.VehicleType
                            select row;

            dtGetVihcale = rowsdata.CopyToDataTable();         

            //dtGetVihcale = rowsdata.CopyToDataTable();

        }

    }
```

> please see below image  i want only one record at one time in
>   datatable how to add through loop data in datatable

[I want insert record different datatable through loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWaZZ.jpg)

[but in rowsdata its show 36 record but i want only one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxpkh.jpg)

Comment: The error is exactly what it says: no DataRows. Your linq returned no data, you must verifty rowData variable prior to copy data.

Comment: i want copy rowsdata into dtGetVichale datatable ,